# Is it possible to precompile graphs then run in parallel?

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the CS224D code for recursive neural networks (see: http://cs224d.stanford.edu/syllabus.html Pset 3 Solutions)

How the code works is a new graph is compiled for each training example since each tree has a different shape, but this is suboptimal for running minibatches, etc. I have a similar recursive graph but with larger input, so I need a solution that is more parallelizable.

I have the idea to precompile graphs and load them asynchronously along with their data to GPU, similar to how a queue works. Then offload the minibatch of results, compute the combined gradients, then back-propagate. The idea is that I can account for variable input, and also take advantage of the GPU (have my cake and eat it too).

Is something like this feasible?